# Removing [meeting] tag?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through old posts, and I noticed that the only posts flagged [meeting](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meeting) have a negative score.  I believe that there are not enough things unique about a meeting room (e.g. a Polycom is used in my office also), that we can remove this tag.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. I've removed the tag from the questions it was attached to - the system will automatically remove the tag itself within 24 hours.